# keep inputs values after search cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a page with a search function and I want to keep the values selected this way if I want to make another search I don't have to refill all the inputs.

Those are my inputs that i want to keep the value:

```html
<?= $this->Form->input('search', ['placeholder' => 'Search', 'label' => false]); ?>

<input type="radio" name="multimedia_type_id" id="radio1" value="1">

<input type="radio" name="multimedia_type_id" id="radio2" value="2">

<input type="radio" name="multimedia_type_id" id="radio3" value="3">

<?= $this->Form->input('category_id', ['class' => 'electdown',
                                                               'label' => false,
                                                               'empty' => 'Categories',
                                                               'default' => 'Categories',
                                                               'options' => $categories
                                                              ]); ?>
```

how can I keep the values?

Comment: Try using $this->Form->radio() instead http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::radio

Comment: ok, changed but that not solve the problem

Comment: Are you using the CakeDC search plugin by chance? https://github.com/CakeDC/search

Comment: no, i'm not using any plugin